# My interpretation of kinetic theory of gases predicts empirically false thermal decomposition temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory, chemical-potential

I have an intuition that, for 50% thermal decomposition of water gas, the average collision energy must equal the $2H_2 + O_2 \iff 2H_2O$ enthalpy of reaction divided per unit molecule. I have another intuition that the collision energy between molecules in a gas is a gaussian distribution centered on the average kinetic energy per molecule, so the average collision energy equals the average kinetic energy.

However, proceeding:

The temperature at which half of the molecules in water are decomposed into (mostly) hydrogen and oxygen gas is about $3300K$.

Where $k$ is the Botlzmann constant, $T$ is temperature in kelvins, $\bar K$ is average kinetic energy of a molecule, for an polyatomic nonlinear molecular gas with 3 translational, 3 rotational, and 3 vibrational degrees of freedom, kinetic theory predicts

$\bar K \approx \frac {9}{2} kT = 1.3 eV$

But the $\Delta H$ of water is about $480kJ/mol$ hence on average $5.0 eV$ per molecule.

I suspect that one or both of my intuitions must be incorrect. Where does the missing $3.7 eV$ come from?

Comment: What happens when you reconsider how complex reaction systems are comprised of elemental reaction steps?

Comment: I assume the Chemistry SE site is more suited for this. The reaction equilibrium constant $K$ is directly linked to the reaction Gibbs energy for given $T$.  $$\Delta_r G(T) =  \Delta_r H(T) - T \Delta_r S(T)=-RT \ln{(K(T))}$$

Comment: Rhetorical question: What fraction of water in a bathtube must have enough energy to skip the bathtube edge for 50% of water to get out of it in the end?

Comment: @poutnik I don't see the relevance of the bathtub question. If we add kinetic energy randomly to each volume element of the water we'll just heat the water, not remove it from the tub. It is a momentum problem that couples to kinetic energy by the momentum-energy relationship; it can't be reversed to a kinetic energy problem that couples to momentum.

Comment: I did not mean thermal energy, but mechanical one, all being a mechanical analogy. Imagine a child playing with water. Any  fraction of water with enough kinetic energy and suitable direction of motion *in macroscopic scale* can lead to any fraction of escaped water, only the time needed for that would differ. It is implied the lost energy is continually supplied, similarly as for water vapor to be dissociated.